# Iframe cutting off most of it's content inside of a <div>

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to imbed graphs from the FRED Economic Reserve into my website, and it displays the top left of the graph, yet it cuts off the rest of the content.

Here is the part of the index.html file that places the iframe:

```
<div class="box" id="retailbox">
    <iframe src="http:////research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/graph/graph-landing.php?g=GEt" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

Here are the relevant parts of the CSS:

```
#retailbox {
    border: solid #a08db7;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 38% 53% auto;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem: [image]

I tried adding this bit of css from another topic and editing the html accordingly to no avail:

```
div#content iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Edit**:
When I allow scrolling, the iframe is clearly the correct size for the div, it is just not showing most of the content.
Thanks in advance, hopefully I'm just making a careless mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xd7rU/) with a working example. I removed the margin as it was annoying to debug with.

```
#retailbox {
    border: solid #a08db7;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Basically:

1. You had an issue with your selector not selecting anything `div#content iframe` doesn't exist.
2. You were setting `height: 100%;` and `width: 100%;` on an element that does not have a relative parent with a set width/height so it had nothing to calculate from.

Comment: Thanks so much, worked perfectly.  I didn't change anything in the #retail box because of how the rest of the site works, but when I added your iframe part, it worked perfectly. Thanks also for the explanation, I am not very confident with html or css and you explained it well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the iframe some style guidance on how to display itself. It does not expand to contain its contents:

```
#frame {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
position: absolute; 


}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3RKg7/